# How to properly decode url with unicode in C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, urldecode

From my referrer log I'm trying to decode the referrers, but it looks like `%81` and `%8A` are not valid percent encoding so I get `ri�0�9o`.

I need to send the decoded string through a websocket, right now I get `Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.` on the browser side.

Are these even valid percent encodes? How can I know if they are valid or not?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void urldecode2(char *dst, const char *src) {
    char a, b;
    while(*src) {
        if((*src == '%') && ((a = src[1]) && (b = src[2])) && (isxdigit(a) && isxdigit(b))) {
            if(a >= 'a')
                a -= 'a'-'A';
            if(a >= 'A')
                a -= ('A' - 10);
            else
                a -= '0';
            if(b >= 'a')
                b -= 'a'-'A';
            if(b >= 'A')
                b -= ('A' - 10);
            else
                b -= '0';
            *dst++ = 16*a+b;
            src+=3;
        } else if(*src == '+') {
            *dst++ = ' ';
            src++;
        } else {
            *dst++ = *src++;
        }
    }
    *dst++ = '\0';
}

int main () {
    const char *in = "http://www.google.co.in/search?q=cari%810%8A9o";
    char out[100];

    urldecode2(out, in);
    printf("%s\n", out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%81` and `%8A` are perfectly valid %-escapes, but the result is not a UTF-8 string. What do you expect the search string to be, in human-readable characters?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The website that was hit by this referrer is in Spanish, I assume it should read `cariño`. Though the site referring this is from www.google.co.in.

Comment: ñ is %c3%b1. I have no idea where the codes you cite come from.

Comment: I agree. We're hosting a bunch of sites so I can't tell if that's the intended search string, I'm just trying to parse all referrers and output percent decoded valid utf8 strings. Is there a way to convert `%81` and `%8A` to utf8? or do I need to strip this chars?

Comment: Roughly speaking, a utf-8 sequence is either a single character whose code is less than hex 80, or a lead character followed by one to three follow characters. Lead character s are in the range hex C0 to hex FF (actually C2 to F4) and follow characters are hex 80 to hex BF. So %81 and %8A can never start a utf-8 sequence. To be more precise, Cx and Dx start two-character sequences, Ex start three character sequences and Fx start four-character sequences. If you get a sequence which doesn't follow those rules, dropping it is probably the only reasonable action.

Comment: I think that answers the question. Thanks for the explaining this, very useful info.

Comment: I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%81` and `%8A` are perfectly valid %-escapes, but the result is not a UTF-8 string. URLs are not required to be UTF-8 strings, but these days they usually are.

It looks to me like some very strange double encoding has happened. There is no convention I know of which uses three-digit %-encodings, but that's what it looks like you have in that URL. On the assumption that the intention was to encode the Spanish word "cariño" (care, affection, fondness), it should have been `cari%C3%B1o` in UTF-8, or `cari%F1o` in ISO-8859-1/Windows-1252 (which usually show up in URLs by accident).

The rules for valid UTF-8 sequences are simple enough that you can check for a valid sequence using a regular expression. Not all valid sequences are mapped to characters, and 66 of them are mapped explicitly as "not characters", but all valid sequences should be accepted by a conforming decoder even if it later rejects the decoded character as semantically incorrect.

A UTF-8 sequence is a one-to-four byte sequence corresponding to one of the following patterns: (taken from the Unicode standard, table 3.7)

```
    Byte 1      Byte 2      Byte 3      Byte 4
    ------      ------      ------      ------
    00..7F        --          --          --
    C2..DF      80..BF        --          --
    E0          A0..BF      80..BF        --
    E1..EC      80..BF      80..BF        --
    ED          80..9F      80..BF        --
    EE..EF      80..BF      80..BF        --
    F0          90..BF      80..BF      80..BF
    F1..F3      80..BF      80..BF      80..BF
    F4          80..8F      80..BF      80..BF
```

Anything else is illegal. (So codes C0, C1 and F5 through FF cannot appear at all.) In particular, the hex codes 81 and 8A can never start a UTF-8 sequence.

Since there is no good way to know what might be meant by an invalid sequence, the simplest thing is just to strip them out.